# PHP strstr difference issue

Tags: php, scripting, strstr

So currently I have a problem. I have this snippet of code to see if a phrase is present in another phrase:

```
if(strstr($matches[1], $query))
```

So for example if:

```
$matches[1] = "arctic white"
$query = "arctic"
```

In the case above, the code would detect that the phrase "arctic" is in the phrase "arctic white" although, what I want is for it to detect if it is inside words as well and not just phrases.

For example if:

```
$matches[1] = "antarctica"
$query = "arctic"
```

In that case the script would NOT detect the word "arctic" in "antarctica" although it is. So I was wondering, how can I edit `if(strstr($matches[1], $query))` so it would detect ALL words that have the $query content in it? Please help!

Comment: It already does: http://ideone.com/eKGgd.

Comment: you should be using `strpos()` instead.

Comment: It already detects just fine. I am guessing you actually want to find the words which contain the $query contents?

Comment: Yep, I want to detect all words that contain the $query content.

Comment: @Gokhan137: Ok, that's not what your question says at all.  Please edit your question to explain exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use preg_match() for much better result. The preg_match doesn't encompass regular expressions only. It can do exactly what you need. i.e.:

```
if (preg_match("/arctic/i", "antarctica")) {
    // it is there do something
} else {
    // it is not there do something else
}
```

btw, the small "i" means case sensitivity, check PHP manual for more examples: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: He corrected his post. He wants the words, you should show him how to collect matches.

Comment: but he is showing just one array key -> value. Does he mean the key will hold a long text which needs to be searched ?  Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

use `strpos()`

example:

```
$word = "antarctica";
$find = "arctic";

$i = strpos($word, $find);

if($i === false)
{
echo "not found";
}

else
{
echo "found";
}
```